# Merge two sorted iterators without replace

Tags: python

I need to merge two iterators. I wrote this function:

```
def merge_no_repeat(iter1, iter2, key=None):
    """
    a = iter([(2, 'a'), (4, 'a'), (6, 'a')])
    b = iter([(1, 'b'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'b'), (4, 'b'), (5, 'b'), (6, 'b'), (7, 'b'), (8, 'b')])
    key = lambda item: item[0]
    fusion_no_repeat(a, b, key) ->
                iter([(1, 'b'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (4, 'a'), (5, 'b'), (6, 'a'), (7, 'b'), (8, 'b')])
    :param iter1: sorted iterator
    :param iter2: sorted iterator
    :param key: lambda get sorted key, default: lambda x: x
    :return: merged iterator
    """
    if key is None:
        key = lambda x: x
    element1 = next(iter1, None)
    element2 = next(iter2, None)
    while element1 is not None or element2 is not None:
        if element1 is None:
            yield element2
            element2 = next(iter2, None)
        elif element2 is None:
            yield element1
            element1 = next(iter1, None)
        elif key(element1) > key(element2):
            yield element2
            element2 = next(iter2, None)
        elif key(element1) == key(element2):
            yield element1
            element1 = next(iter1, None)
            element2 = next(iter2, None)
        elif key(element1) < key(element2):
            yield element1
            element1 = next(iter1, None)
```

This function works. But I think it's too complicated. Is it possible to make this function easiest using *Python Standard Libraries*?

Comment: [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)?

Comment: This questions is probably better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MathiasEttinger itertools.chain won't return a sorted iterator.

Comment: Would the iterator be always like that (as you gave in your example?)

Comment: @JulienGrenier `sorted(itertools.chain(iter1,iter2),key)` then.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger then you have to consume the whole `.chain` up-front, which is somewhat inefficient with large iterators (and impossible with infinite ones).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you. I didn't know about http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
def merge_no_repeat(iter1, iter2, key=None):
    if key is None:
        key = lambda x: x
    ref = next(iter1, None)
    for elem in iter2:
        key_elem = key(elem) # caching value so we won't compute it for each value in iter1 that is before this one
        while ref is not None and key_elem > key(ref):
            # Catch up with low values from iter1
            yield ref
            ref = next(iter1, None)
        if ref is None or key_elem < key(ref):
            # Catch up with low values from iter2, eliminate duplicates
            yield elem
    # Update: I forgot to consume iter1 in the first version of this code
    for elem in iter1:
        # Use remaining items of iter1 if needed
        yield elem
```

I assumed that the iterators wouldn't return `None` values except when completely consumed, since you have `if element1 is None:` and `elif element1 is None:` tests in your original code.

---

Examples:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> list(merge_no_repeat(
...     iter([(2, 'a'), (4, 'a'), (6, 'a')]),
...     iter([(1, 'b')]),
...     itemgetter(0)))
[(1, 'b'), (2, 'a'), (4, 'a'), (6, 'a')]
>>> list(merge_no_repeat(
...     iter([(2, 'a'), (4, 'a'), (6, 'a')]),
...     iter([(1, 'b'),(7, 'b'), (8, 'b')]),
...     itemgetter(0)))
[(1, 'b'), (2, 'a'), (4, 'a'), (6, 'a'), (7, 'b'), (8, 'b')]
>>> list(merge_no_repeat(
...     iter([(2, 'a'), (4, 'a'), (6, 'a')]),
...     iter([(1, 'b'),(3, 'b'), (4,'b'),(5,'b'),(7, 'b'), (8, 'b')]),
...     itemgetter(0)))
[(1, 'b'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (4, 'a'), (5, 'b'), (6, 'a'), (7, 'b'), (8, 'b')]
```

Comment: First of all you need to change the `is None` to `is not None` in last `if` also but then still it returns a wrong result! Try with my example!

Comment: @Kasramvd in the last if, `a is None` is actually a test to check if `iter1` is consumed.

Comment: Whoops, `a` was in fact `ref`. Edited

Answer (score 2):

The [pytoolz library](http://toolz.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) has [an implementation](https://github.com/pytoolz/toolz/blob/master/toolz/itertoolz.py#L114) of this. It doesn't look like it uses any non-standard-library functions so if you really don't want to include an external library you could probably just copy the code.

If you're interested in speed there's also a [cython implementation](https://github.com/pytoolz/cytoolz) of pytoolz.

Answer (score 1):

One, this fails if either of the iterators returns None, you should probably catch StopIteration exceptions. Two, once one of the iterators has no more values, you can just return all the rest of the values of the other one.

I think this is easier to make if you use a small wrapper class around an iterator that makes the next value visible:

```
class NextValueWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, iterator):
        self.iterator = iterator
        self.next_value = None
        self.finished = False
        self.get()

    def get(self):
        if self.finished: return  # Shouldn't happen, maybe raise an exception
        value = self.next_value
        try:
            self.next_value = next(self.iterator)
        except StopIteration:
            self.finished = True
        return value
```

Then the code becomes:

```
def merge(iter1, iter2, key=None):
    if key is None:
        key = lambda x: x

    wrap1 = NextValueWrapper(iter1)
    wrap2 = NextValueWrapper(iter2)

    while not (wrap1.finished and wrap2.finished):
        if (wrap2.finished or 
               (not wrap1.finished and 
                key(wrap1.next_value) <= key(wrap2.next_value))):
            yield wrap1.get()
        else:
            yield wrap2.get()
```

This is untested. And it repeats. And it's Python 2, out of habit. Making it non-repeating is left as an exercise for the reader, I hadn't noticed that was a requirement too...

Comment: `NexValueWrapper.get` returns `None` unconditionnally. Thus if neither iterator is finished, your code yield `None`.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger: Yes (forgot a return statement), and another bug, the for loop yielding values forgets to yield the next value. Luckily I just took a shower, that brings clarity, will edit :-)

Answer (score 1):

As I'm just working on a problem that needs this, here is the solution I came up with. I worked out my problem in Haskell first. I believe looking at an idiomatic Haskell solution is instructive.

```hs
merge k [] ys = ys
merge k xs [] = xs
merge k (x:xs) (y:ys) =
  if k y < k x then y:merge k (x:xs) ys
  else x:merge k xs (if k y==k x then ys else (y:ys))
```

The arguments are just lists, but because Haskell is lazy, it works even with infinite lists. `:` is the Haskell list constructor, so `x:xs` is equivalent to `[x]+xs` in Python.

A recursive solution like this is a bit of a non-starter in Python, but we can preserve its essence while transforming the recursion into iteration by trampolining, like this:

```py
from functools import partial

Nil = object()
def merge(xs, ys, k=lambda x:x):
    def nxt(it): return next(it, Nil)
    def tail(it): return lambda: (next(it), tail(it))
    def both(x, y):
        return ((y, tail(ys)) if x is Nil else
                (x, tail(xs)) if y is Nil else
                ((y, partial(both, x, nxt(ys))) if k(y) < k(x) else
                 (x, partial(both, nxt(xs), nxt(ys) if k(x) == k(y) else y))))
    to_yield, extract = both(nxt(xs), nxt(ys))
    while to_yield is not Nil:
        yield to_yield
        to_yield, extract = extract()
```

A few observations about this:

- We create a new unique out-of-band value `Nil` instead of `None` so that the sequences can contain `None` values without interfering with the logic.
- We use the two argument form of `next` with a value to return if the iterator is empty to avoid raising a `StopIteration` exception too early.
- We trampoline by having the `extract` function return the next value to yield *and* the next `extract` function to use. While both iterables are active, the `extract` function is `both`.
- This is Python 2 because that's what I use, but it does mean there's no `yield from` to play out one iterator when the other is empty. Instead, we switch into `tail` mode, which continues trampolining but relies on the single argument form of `next` raising `StopIteration` to terminate the process.

Here's an example of it in action:

```
>>> from itertools import islice, imap
>>> mul = lambda x: lambda y: x*y
>>> list(islice(merge(imap(mul(5), count()), imap(mul(3), count())), 20))
[0, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15, 18, 20, 21, 24, 25, 27, 30, 33, 35, 36, 39, 40]
```